# show unedited version of model data

Tags: database, django, duplicates

I have an Entry model as follows:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tags)
```

Now, whenever a user creates or edits an `Entry` object we send it to the moderation queue and the object is not available to the default manager for `Entry` object until it has been moderated. It makes sense when a user is initially creating an object but when a user is edit the entry object it disappears from the search results. We also offer users to save or bookmark, different entries. so the edited Entry object is not available in the saved entries anymore until it has been moderated.

What I am looking to do is to have the old `Entry` show up until the edited `Entry` is under moderation once the edited entry object is moderated we can replace the edited entry with the original one.

One way I can think of is to create a different Entry Object for each edit a user makes but I am not quite sure if that is a feasible and a sensible approach to handle this situation wouldn't it just have a lot of duplicate data in the database ??

#### Questions:

1. what are my options ? (I would also like to know which ones would be the best performance-wise)
2. Is there a way I can achieve this without duplicating the object ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if the number of objects that are sent to the moderation queue is low to moderate, you can have a `ManyToMany` (Infact a One to Many is what you want) field which keeps references to the versions from the `Entry` object.

If this is not feasible, you can look into [django-pickle-field](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield/) which lets you store any object types into the database. So, you can  create an additional `nullable` column, in which you would save the form data on edit as-is and make it available in the moderation queue.

So, the logic for moderation queue is something like:

```
MyObject.objects.filter(pickle_field__isnull=False)
```

Once the moderator approves, override the field data into the object.
else, discard the picklefield.

If you want to allow multiple edits, or keep track of moderation history, you can make that a ManyToMany with more info (such as edited by, moderated by, etc.) in the intermediary table.